# Difference between commands

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates, dpkg

What is the difference between the following?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ubuntu-files
```

plus

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ./ubuntu-files
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: Manual that explains it all and more: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#s-record

Comment: in sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade    what does dselect do

Comment: By the way... your code is flawed. I added i a `-` and `sudo apt-get -y update`. Plus I put a break in the last set: the 1st command you issue on your OLD install. The other 3 on the new install ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st part is just a normal update/upgrade.

The last part is about saving your package list and restoring them into a new system.

Let's say you have a crashed system and can get to a commandprompt.

`pkg --get-selections|grep -v deinstall>ubuntu-files` makes a file list of all installed packages (when using `apt-get`!). You save that file on a FDD, USB stick or disc.

After you installed your new system you copy that backup to `/tmp/` and `sudo dpkg --set-selections <./ubuntu-files` will set it up and

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

will install **only those packages** you had installed (with apt-get) in the older system.

Comment: why should we do "apt-get dselect-upgrade" what will happen if i do "apt-get upgrade"

Comment: Like it said in the answer: dselect installs the selected files from the file. upgrade will upgrade -all- packages.